# WildFly RestEasy UTF-8 Response

Tags: utf-8, wildfly, resteasy

I'm trying to return russian text:

```
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN + ";charset=utf-8")

return Response.status(200).entity("Русский текст.").build();
```

Before I started reading standalone-full.xml, I was getting normal Russian text, but when I changed this in standalone.bat:

```
set "SERVER_OPTS=--server-config=standalone-full.xml"
```

I'm getting something like this.

[image]

This don't help me:

[image]

Comment: If it's only an issue with standalone-full.xml you might want to compare that with your standalone.xml if that's the one that works. Maybe there's an encoding configured somewhere. The system property won't work because WildFly does not use Tomcat. Also can you specify the version of WildFly you're using?

Comment: I use wildfly-23.0.1.Final. I'm beginner in wildfly, and I don't know where wildfly get default config because default string in standalone.bat is

```
set "SERVER_OPTS=%*"
```